# Mysql query help - count rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have two different tables trackingevent and link

Trackingevent looks like

```
eventName|eventStamp
SHARE_FACEBOOK|2011-01-20 14:05:40
SHARE_TWEET|2011-01-20 14:47:57
SHARE_FLICKR|2011-01-20 15:08:58
SHARE_STATION_LOGIN|2011-01-20 15:09:09
EMAIL_SHARE|2011-01-20 15:10:13
CONTEST_ENTRY:BLAH DATA|2011-01-20 15:10:13
CONTEST_ENTRY:BLAH DATA|2011-01-20 15:10:13
```

and link looks like

```
id|emailSub
6|1
7|0
8|1
9|0
```

And what I need to do is I need to count all the SHARE_FACEBOOK
and all the SHARE_TWEET
and all the SHARE_FLICKR
and all the SHARE_STATION_LOGIN
and all the COPNTEST_ENTRIES **(Without the rest of the data after the :)**
AND EMAIL_SHARE
and somehow combine those with the amount of emailSub (equals to 1)
and amount of id.

So I get a returned array sort of like

```
EMAIL_SHARE     77
SHARE_FLICKR    9
SHARE_FACEBOOK  105
SHARE_STATION_LOGIN     223
SHARE_TWEET     18
# of ID's
# of emailsub=1
CONTEST_ENTERIES 550
```

I can get the first part of it using
SELECT eventName, COUNT(*) FROM `trackingevent` GROUP BY eventName
But I am confused with how to get the # of ID's in the link the # of emailsubs=1 and the number of CONTEST_ENTRY:BLAH DATA (the blah data changes).

Would I have to do three different sql queries and combine the data? Or could I somehow combine them into a single one or?

Comment: wow, who on earth thought that would be a good DB design? Colon-separated values instead of (god forbid) a 'type' column! None the less, being saddled with bad designs is less than fun, so i'll start drafting an aswer :P

Comment: It's not my design sadly, the database admin guy did it. And regardless of how mad I am getting apparently it would cost less to have me spend 50 hours fixing it then have them spend 2 hours.

Comment: could we get some column names, and what do the id's reference? there is no ID you have given us on any other column... and what do you mean by "somehow combine them"?

Comment: I'll answer in reverse, "somehow combine them" I mean a join statement or something. Link table will have the ID (id|emailSub) there are two different tables there. Column names are eventName and eventStamp for trackingevent and id and emailSub for link.

Comment: @Steven: what hes asking is how does `link` relate to `trackingevent` its not evident in what you posted and completely necessary. Actually it would be even better if you could do a `show create table` on each of those and then post the schema output it gives.

Comment: right, so what does the id refer to? there must be an id column in the trackingEvents table too

Comment: Sorry, my confusion. The ID is just to get the TOTAL number of rows in the database. I figured you could count the ID since you are counting the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you the count of each type using the prefix

```
SELECT LEFT(eventName,INSTR(CONCAT(eventName,':'),':')) as prefix, count(*)
FROM trackingevent
GROUP BY LEFT(eventName,INSTR(CONCAT(eventName,':'),':'))
```

You'll have to answer the questions in the comments if this isn't what you were asking for